# Previous day Record count in my sql

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I am not perfect in mysql queries i tried this code to get previous date record count

code snippet

```
SELECT id, date, COUNT(IF(date<= date-INTERVAL 1 DAY, id, NULL))
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date
```

this query gives me prev day value is 0.

help me out to get previous day count of id

this is what i need

```
date        count
-------------------
2014-01-01  0
2014-01-02  13
2014-01-03  55
```

Comment: previous all days or just yesterday day?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: actually i need both :D

Comment: this is what i need
date  count
-------------------
2014-01-01 0
2014-01-02 13
2014-01-03 55

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you rather look for something like this, to count id's from yesterday:

```
select
  date(dt),
  count(id)
from
  table_name
where
  date(dt) < date(now())
group by
  date(dt)
```

Comment: so you want all previous dates. simply change the where to: where date(dt) < date(now())